# How can I filter nested objects with unknown keys?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cups

I'd like to create a new array with information filtered from a nested object with unknown keys.

The data comes from CUPS API and the keys are printer names.
I'd like to filter on for example `'printer-state' === 3`.

```
const data = {
    'Expedition': {
        'printer-is-shared': false,
        'printer-state': 4,
        'printer-state-message': '',
        'printer-state-reasons': ['none'],
    },
    'Serverroom': {
        'printer-is-shared': false,
        'printer-state': 3,
        'printer-state-message': '',
        'printer-state-reasons': ['none'],
    }
}
```

Thanks

I've tried Array.filter() but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What did you try that did not work? And Java !== JavaScript `Object.entries(data).filter()`

Comment: this is an Object and not an Array you can not perform a filter method

Comment: how do you want the result ?

Comment: What is the output you want from above object, there is no matter what you are using rather focusing on any specific methiod.

Comment: As Id written it up by the time it was closed https://jsfiddle.net/w1bkvcts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    const data = {
    'Expedition': {
        'printer-is-shared': false,
        'printer-state': 4,
        'printer-state-message': '',
        'printer-state-reasons': ['none'],
    },
    'Serverroom': {
        'printer-is-shared': false,
        'printer-state': 3,
        'printer-state-message': '',
        'printer-state-reasons': ['none'],
    }
}
const filterObjectByKeyValue = (obj, key, value) => {
      return Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(k => obj[k][key] === value)
        .reduce((res, k) => ((res[k] = obj[k]), res), {});
};

console.log(filterObjectByKeyValue(data,'printer-state',3))
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks! However can you explain how the reduce function works?

Comment: Also, How would one return an array instead of an object with the filter results?